Some objects are only selectable in the outliner
I've been working on this model for a while, and suddenly, some object/assets i add are not selectable in the viewport. I can only select them in the outliner. The happened with a random selection of objects in the file and I already tried so many things (like making sure it doesn't have its selection disabled).
Another thing i want to add is that selecting a "non selectable object" in my scene actually selects another random object that has nothing to do with it
Does anyone have any idea on what I could do?


Where is their origin point? If it's no where near the geometry and they are half mixed with other objects like that plane the program might be getting confused as to what you actually want to select when you click a specific area

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

I found the origin of the problem, but not the reason. It was some imported Revit geometry using the Speckle Addon that messed up the selection of other objects for some reason. I just had to get rid of those.
